# Can I find the name of a popup window from the HTML source?

Tags: javascript, html

I can get the name of the popup window in JavaScript by `window.name`. Is there any way, I can get this by looking at the HTML source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The name is defined as property of the window object which is not present in the HTML source.